# Convert Adobe Reader form document to general pdf

Tags: macos, pdf, file-conversion, adobe

I have problems with a provider that refuses to deliver important documents in anything but Adobe *Reader* specific documents. I think these are with Adobe *Experience Manager* pdf forms. Their documents open in *Preview* or *Skim* and similar with a note stating

> "The document you are trying to load requires Adobe Reader 8 or higher".

The document **isn't encrypted** and is said to have been made with Adobe *LifeCycle Designer* 11.0 and is in pdf 1.7 format.
I have extremely few pdf documents I can't open. Theirs are about the only ones.

Are there any options for converting a Reader pdf, like this one, to a common pdf format? I tried some online tool. but I think it just copied the content.

No! I will not install Adobe *Reader* as it's a piece of junk.

Comment: @Steve, and a large majority of these can't read this pdf file, which was actually the point of the whole question.
If you can tell which third party pdf viewers that can open and display this kind of pdf document I'm all ears.

Comment: Please @Steve, stop replying with circular answers. If you don't have an answer to the actual question asked, then simply don't post anything.

Comment: @Steve, Yes, I figured out the obvious already without your eloquent assistance. I feel you make too much of this. Months can pass and an answer may be found and shared. 

There may be detailed knowledge about the formats and technologies involved that may explain the difficulties devising a good technique, and I welcome such information and I will seek it myself. Speculation doesn't really add anything to this endeavor.